# mobile ci on cloudbees jenkins and soasta cloudtest

Tags: jenkins, xcodebuild, cloudbees

I'm following the practice outlined on [this blog post](http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/12/mobile-builds-with-jenkins-in-cloud.html) in which an .ipa archive of my xcode project gets built on a slave by a CloudBees Jenkins job.

The slave now appears as a node in my Jenkins configuration and when the job is run, the xcode project is downloaded correctly from CloudBees.  However, the job has a problem creating folders in /Applications/xcode.app.  I could use some help troubleshooting the following stack trace:

```
Started by user Wil Pannell
Building remotely on mobile-slave in workspace /Users/WPANNELL/jenkins/workspace/ios-mobile-image-browser
Copied 275 artifacts from "gwt-mobile-image-browser" build number 3
Unable to access upstream artifacts area /home/ventana/hudson_home/jobs/gwt-mobile-image-browser/modules/com.ventana.gwt$mobilebrowser/builds/2013-01-07_20-08-56/archive. Does source project archive artifacts?
Working directory is /Users/WPANNELL/jenkins/workspace/ios-mobile-image-browser/ios/VentanaMobileBrowser.xcodeproj.
[VentanaMobileBrowser.xcodeproj] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
Xcode 4.5.2
Build version 4G2008a
Fetching marketing version number (CFBundleShortVersionString) from project.
[VentanaMobileBrowser.xcodeproj] $ /usr/bin/agvtool mvers -terse1
No marketing version found (CFBundleShortVersionString).
Marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) found in project configuration: .
Fetching technical version number (CFBundleVersion) from project.
[VentanaMobileBrowser.xcodeproj] $ /usr/bin/agvtool vers -terse
No marketing version found (CFBundleVersion)
Technical version (CFBundleVersion) found in project configuration: .
Updating marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) to: 2.2.4
[VentanaMobileBrowser.xcodeproj] $ /usr/bin/agvtool new-marketing-version 2.2.4
Setting CFBundleShortVersionString of project project to: 
    2.2.4.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/agvtool: line 319: project.pbxproj/project.pbxproj.new1: Not a directory
mv: rename project.pbxproj/project.pbxproj.new1 to project.pbxproj/project.pbxproj: Not a directory
Updating technical version (CFBundleVersion) to: 2.2.4
[VentanaMobileBrowser.xcodeproj] $ /usr/bin/agvtool new-version -all 2.2.4
Setting version of project project to: 
    2.2.4.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/agvtool: line 139: project.pbxproj/project.pbxproj.new1: Not a directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/agvtool: line 140: project.pbxproj/project.pbxproj.new2: Not a directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/agvtool: line 141: project.pbxproj/project.pbxproj.new3: Not a directory
Also setting CFBundleVersion key (assuming it exists)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/agvtool: line 145: project.pbxproj/project.pbxproj.new4: Not a directory
mv: rename project.pbxproj/project.pbxproj.new4 to project.pbxproj/project.pbxproj: Not a directory
rm: project.pbxproj/project.pbxproj.new1: Not a directory
rm: project.pbxproj/project.pbxproj.new2: Not a directory
rm: project.pbxproj/project.pbxproj.new3: Not a directory


Marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) used by Jenkins to produce the IPA: 2.2.4
Technical version (CFBundleVersion) used by Jenkins to produce the IPA: 2.2.4
Going to invoke xcodebuild:target: VentanaMobileBrowser, sdk: iphoneos, project: DEFAULT, configuration: Debug, clean: NO, symRoot: DEFAULT, configurationBuildDir: DEFAULT
[VentanaMobileBrowser.xcodeproj] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -target VentanaMobileBrowser -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug build DSTROOT=. clean install
Build settings from command line:
    DSTROOT = .
    SDKROOT = iphoneos6.0

xcodebuild: error: 'project.pbxproj' is not a project file.
Build step 'XCode' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: My jenkins xcode configuration was incorrect.  I specified the Xcode Project File in the field reserved for the Xcode Project Directory.  I'll post back here if I encounter further problems.

Comment: Remember you can answer your own question and even accept the answer, making a record of what you were confused by and what the resolution was.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @JesseGlick, but when I tried I was warned that my reputation wasn't good enough to do that and that I should comment instead.

Comment: Wil - can you past the answer in your comment and I can post it as an answer so we can close this?

Comment: @MichaelNeale--sorry I did not see this until now, but I'm afraid I don't follow your instructions.  Please clarify what you wish me to do to close this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My jenkins xcode configuration was incorrect. I specified the Xcode Project File in the field reserved for the Xcode Project Directory. I'll post back here if I encounter further problems.